# Add more than 15K items in WordPress Database without overwhelming the server?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, wordpress, guzzle

We have created a Crawler using GuzzleHTTP and other associated libraries hosted on AWS Servers which crawls and gives us around 5,000 products from 1 site alone and we have in total 4 sites, so the count of items comes upto around 15k+.

Now the Crawler is working fine & we are able to crawl all the site in under an hour and build JSON files.

Then we are exporting the data from those JSON files into WordPress DB with the items being a post and any additional data as post_meta and terms and taxonomies. We are doing this right now using WP Ajax hooks and filters and a loop(ofcourse).

But it is taking a hell lot of time to export and the chance of server giving a timeout is very high, which will be as normally Apache servers are not meant to take such a load.

We need to know the best way possible to do this.

1. Do we create a DB on the AWS itself and somehow connect it to WordPress? If yes, then how will we manage the relationships between the custom posts and its meta and terms. As if we add the data on the server where the WordPress is hosted we can use WordPress functions to create posts and associate data accordingly.
2. Do we run a CRON Job on the WordPress server's end and give more power to the server, so that the timeout issue is not there. We are on Site Ground's servers.
3. Or this there a better way to do this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: 15K items shouldn't even cause your server to break a sweat. You might need to set your timeouts in php.ini higher (even if termporarily) but there's no reason you shouldn't be able to handle hundreds of thousands of records.

Comment: How are you handling your inserts?  I had a long running thing that does an ETL operation (read from file read from db compare the 2 sets of 50k records and write out differences then update DB with data from file) , would take long time to run - 10 minutes or more at times. Cut it down to an average of just under 3 minutes by collecting all data and then doing a single DB connection, loop through the insert statements, and then disconnect.  Prior method would connect/disconnect for each insert.

Comment: @Difster How much timeout value you think would be good enough? We have set_time_limit(3000); Thanks!

Comment: @ivanivan We are handling our inserts with WordPress AJAX Hooks and Filters and default WordPress Functions to insert post wp_insert_post. i have called AJAX request within same AJAX as to run another request only when the previous one is completed, so that we can cancel the action in middle if we wish to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience I have created more than 50 000 products on wordpress/woocommerce.

First time I used woo commerce API to create products from an external server, it's very easy to do it but will require to much time. Here is documentation  [http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction][1]

The best way for me is to use WordPress hooks it will be faster than api. You can set the timeout to -1 and it will not display anymore.

In my opinion, wordpress is not the best choice to deal with huge amounts of data.

Good luck

Comment: Hey @xhuljo, I think WordPress is not an issue here. What I may be missing is the Server Configuration or the way I am looking at this prospect and going about it. There is something wrong with my plan. As i am crawling the Data on AWS and creating JSON and then importing that JSON into WordPress using Async AJAX and loop. Thanks!